# How Can I Set Global Timezone and Change Time in React?

Tags: reactjs

How can I set the time zone globally in react? Is it possible? I know the new Date() of javascript actually gives the time zone of the system. But I want to set the time zone in one file in react application and re use it. And when I will change the time, the time will also be changed according to the specific time zone. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hey this is not a react related question, I would say more of a JS question but what I normally do is to use Luxon, you need to install the library an afterwards what I do is this:

```
// src/utils/luxon/index.ts
import {DateTime, Settings} from 'luxon'

// Example to set EST as the default timezone in the app.
Settings.defaultZoneName = 'America/New_York'

export {DateTime, Settings}
```

Then I just import that utils file and use the DateTime object to parse and handle dates.

So if you have lets say for example an epoch date you can parse it like this

```
import {DateTime} from 'utils/luxon'
const epochDate = 1597354080
const luxonDate = DateTime.fromSeconds(epochReleaseDate)
console.log(luxonDate.toLocaleString(DateTime.TIME_SIMPLE))
```

If you click this [page](https://www.epochconverter.com/timezones?q=1597354080&tz=America%2FNew_York)  you will notice that the current est time for that epoch should return **Thursday August 13, 2020 17:28:00** (pm)

You can parse those dates to Javascript date objects but I suggest you to get used to luxon because it makes working with dates pretty easy. Just remember that the Date returned by luxon is way different than the Js Date object so don't combine them, instead use the parsing methods of luxon to convert a Js Date to Luxon Date and vice versa

Answer (score 0):

I actually tried to solve the problem this way. to initialize the date in the ui I called the getGlobalDate function instead of calling new Date() in js. And for changing the date I passed the date object to onChangeFormat function and convert the date time.

```js
export const language = "en-US";
export const timeZone = { timeZone: "Pacific/Auckland" };

//to initialize the date
export function getGlobalDate() {
  return new Date().toLocaleString(language, timeZone);
}

//for onChanging the date and convert it to the timzone
export function onChangeFormat(e) {
  const convertToUTC = e.toLocaleString(language, timeZone);
  console.log(convertToUTC);

  return convertToUTC;
}
```